# Facebook's Message TID how to get it

Tags: facebook-graph-api, titanium-mobile, facebook-chat

I'm trying to open an webview on facebook's message(mobile device) page
But I can't find the `tid` that are required to open the chat between two peoples

I want to be able to open a new message chat with someone that the user don't know

here's the URL to access this mobile's devices messange chat: `https://m.facebook.com/messages/read/?tid=id.147453968688586&__user=100000762748887`

this url will open the chat between me and my brother... his facebook's `id` isn't `147453968688586` so I'm trying to know where I should look to find this `tid` to be able to open the url on the chat between two peoples

I already look into facebook's api but didn't find.

Thanks

Comment: someone knows anything about it?

Comment: Found a solution? I'm looking for this too

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution you can use the public id and it will redirect you to the tid :)

```
https://m.facebook.com/messages/thread/*your fbid here*/
```